# Can I (in principle) make an analog fibrescope/borescope for consumer phones using only a fibre optic cable?

Tags: optics, fiber-optics

This question is testing my (limited) understanding of optics.

Here is the background. Many endoscopes work by using a fiber optic light guide to transmit light to a camera which sits at the end of the cable which the user is holding.

There are many consumer borescopes available for smartphones, however all of them use a digital cable (mini/micro USB or usbc) and basically transmit the image from the borescope camera as to the phone as data.

Would it be possible to make a borescope which simply attaches to the lens of the phone camera and transmits the analog image there? What relevant parameters in the cable and the phone's camera might I need to consider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not _an_ optical fiber, it's a _[coherent fiber bundle](https://www.roperscientific.de/fiberoptic.html)_ thousands of fibers arranged so that their positions relative to their neigbors is the same at both ends. The objective lens produces a real image on one end of the bundle, and the eyepiece lets you see a magnified view of the other end.  Not cheap! Mostly replaced these days by miniature video cameras.

Comment: Oh that is great to know. Thank you!!

Comment: Just learned something new: _[Scanning Fiber Endoscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_Fiber_Endoscope_(SFE))_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle it is possible, but it is not feasible economically. You will certainly require some coupling optics after fiber bundle to generate image which could be captured by camera (essentially, an eyepiece).

3 main issues:

1. Low resolution. It is abysmal by today's standard. You are looking at way less than 1 megapixel resolution. You won't impress anyone with this.
2. High cost. Fiber optic bundle could cost more than whole smartphone. At the same time - tiny CMOS camera modules cost <10$. Check out these tiny integrated camera modules: https://www.ovt.com/cameracubechip It is extremely hard for fiber optics to compete with such tiny CMOS camera.
3. Illumination is a major issue. Conventionally - light for such fiber endoscopes is generated by short arc lamp, and is fiber coupled. This is all very expensive.